# init method is calling again and again in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

The `init` method gets called again and again on every request in servlet.
Here is the code:

```
public class PersonInfoController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PersonInfoController() {
        super();
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        Connection connection = Database.getConnection();
        System.out.println("init method");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<PersonInfoServiceI> myList = new ArrayList();
        PersonInfoServiceI instance = new PersonInfoServiceImpl();
        myList = instance.getdata();
        String jsonstring = new Gson().toJson(myList);

        request.setAttribute("List", jsonstring);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("showdata.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("the destory");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, give more information: How do you deploy it, which servlet container, how do you call it, how do you know init is called all over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code init() should call only once when servlet will load on first request. Then after its destruction init() will be called again on new request. In between only your service method will be called. Your code is good having no logical mistakes.
Are you calling init method outside the servlet?
Can you attach you deployment descriptor?